# Bigquery get_project function?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

In bigquery, I am looking for a function that states if a project exists, a la

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()

try:
    client.get_project("my_project")
exept NotFound:
    print("`my project` not found.")
```

This is accomplished for datasets and tables through `get_dataset` and `get_table` respectively.  I could not find anything for `get_project`, unfortunately.

As a complete aside, I cannot find documentation listing methods for `bigquery.Client` anywhere.  Specifically, I just want the page that lists all methods; similar to [this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers) for `tf.keras.layers`.  I looked for anywhere with documentation on the methods (complete with arguments and their respective purpose) but could find neither a github repo or official documentaion.  The best I found is [here](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest/index.html).  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: sorry, what is not working ? what is that you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to know which project is associated with client, this would work.

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
print(client.project)
```

Comment: Would you know where to find docs for google.cloud.bigquery.Client?

Comment: this is the one, but with python I rely more on source code. trying to understand which properties and method

Comment: Could you link the source code?

Comment: if you are using pycharm, just control+click or (cmd+click) on your object, and you will see all the properties, methods associated with it.